# ShareThis Buttons are hiding on resize

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, sharethis

I'm using ShareThis (sharethis-reactjs) buttons. I've added some padding through config (props of the component) but it seems that when I resize the button and if the window is small enough, the buttons are hiding one by one (beginning from the last).

How can I turn of that behaviour? I want to change the padding with media query so they will look smaller when I resize I don't want them to hide BUT when I tried (in CSS media query) to handle this with their element's class name which I found with 'inspect elements' surprisingly nothing changes and they begin to hide one by one (adding display: none to the last).

```
                          <InlineShareButtons
                          className='share-btn-post'
                          config={{
                            alignment: 'center',
                            color: 'social',
                            enabled: 'true',
                            language: 'en',
                            networks: [
                              'facebook',
                              'messenger',
                              'whatsapp',
                              'gmail'
                            ],
                            padding: 40,
                            spacing: 20,
                            radius: 10,
                          }}
                          />
```